# What affects Magic Blockade?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

Does stats other than tower health affect the Apprentice/Adept Magic Blockade?

Does Apprentice/Huntress/Monk Guardians have any effect on Magic Blockade?
[image]

Comment: I don't think it does, because the blocakde only does the defense thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the blockade has no attack, no buffs to attack damage, range, speed, or area of effect would matter (0  * anything is still 0 after all).

The Squire Guardian pet would decrease the damage it takes from enemy attacks, up to 16% for a fully boosted guardian.  There are also a number of pets that would repair the blockade; imp, engineer, mephisto, cain, etc.